# specified JRE installation does not exist (MacOSX)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, adt, osx-mavericks

I'm aware of these nice answers to the previous SO question: [specified JRE installation does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170263/specified-jre-installation-does-not-exist)

However, I can't see how to make use of any of the answers. I've installed the Java JDK, Maven, Ant, Android SDK bundled with Eclipse, and am using Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.5.

Is this as simple as setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable? If so, how do know what to set it to?

I'm brand new to Java so sorry for the noob question.

```
Tims-MacBook-Pro-retina:Github timrpeterson$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
Tims-MacBook-Pro-retina:Github timrpeterson$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_20
```

Comment: How did you install it? If you open a terminal, what is the result of `java -version` and `type java`?

Comment: hey Elliot, added above. I download Java and Eclipse and Android from their respective homepages, e.g., [Android homepage](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html). I installed Maven and Ant using Homebrew.

Comment: And, `type java`? Because that appears to be Java 8.

Comment: yes it looks like version 8, is that bad? `Tims-MacBook-Pro-retina:Github timrpeterson$ type java
java is hashed (/usr/bin/java)`

Comment: No, it's the version you installed. And it's in the PATH, what's giving you that error message?

Comment: When I try and run a hello world app

Comment: Please specify how you try and run a hello world app.

Comment: the simplest way I learned how...http://imgur.com/DCjGgIO

Comment: ok got to the Add part but its not giving me options to add so it looks like I need to plug in the JRE directory? http://imgur.com/cz88rxE

Answer (score 3):

This happens when the project is configured to use a specific JRE on someone's machine, rather than using an Execution Environment (EE). EE's are an abstraction above the physical JRE/JDK that is installed, and allow for portable project configurations (to avoid the problem you've run into). You can fix it by looking at your project in the Package Explorer view and finding its **JRE System Library** node. Right-click that and choose Properties. There you'll be able to select an Execution Environment for the project.

[image]

Depending on how your workspace is set up you might need to also use the Environments button there to configure the desired one in your workspace.

You can also get to the JRE System Library configuration via the project's properties - select the **Java Build Path** section and then the **Libraries** tab. Select the JRE System Library and then use the **Edit...** button to change it.

Comment: Edited the answer with another route to change it.

Comment: Hmm, this must have something to do with the concurrent Android installation as when I just install Eclipse it can find the path, but with the version of Eclipse I installed with Android, none of your or other people suggestions allows me to rescue these path issues.