# The specified JRE installation does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse

I was working on a piece of code in eclipse that was working fine when I stopped work about 8 months ago, when I tried running it today (with no changes made to the files/java installs as far as I know of) I got the above error from eclipse.

I have tried the solution from [Eclipse: The specified JRE installation does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477692/eclipse-the-specified-jre-installation-does-not-exist) to no avail. I reinstalled JRE 8 and set jre1.8 as the default system library in the program but am still having the same issue. It persists whether I use jre1.8, jdk1.7, or an executable environment.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Check if your project settings are different than workspace compiler settings.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Eclipse requires  JDK, JRE is not enough.

Go to Preferences > Add > Standard VM > Directory and add the path of the JDK Home you want to use.

Then add the JRE Library to your Project Build Path (select Java Build Path after right clicking your project)

Comment: So I should have two JRE System Libraries, one jdk and one jre?

I've tried that and run into the same issue. :/

Comment: so if you get JDK 8, you should add the JRE System Library[JavaSE-1.8] to your build path